# Extending a version control system with custom delta algorithm

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial, bazaar

Which mature version control systems allow overriding algorithms of finding and applying delta? Either through plugin or through exteral tool, does not matter.

It must be possible to override internal diff algorithm of a VCS for specific file types. Custom deltas must be stored in the repository to be used by the delta applying algorithm.

Internal binary diff is not acceptable in my case.

I mean exactly overriding algorithms, not displaying the differences using a custom diff program.

Comment: I have a feeling your requirements are overly specific. Phrasing it like this **"Custom deltas must be stored in the repository"** immediately precludes VCS-es that do not store deltas. -- IOW:
How can you still be undecided which VCS you'll be using, yet know that you need to override the algorithm? Is there any reason to assume that a certain VCS will misbehave with your specific file types?
If you need access to the specific deltas, you could just generate them from your trees (have a pre-commit hook, or per-use file attributes in git e.g.)

Comment: “Custom deltas must be stored in the repository…” – Git does not store deltas in the repository but complete files. It only uses deltas for network communication and patches (obviously, but those are in common patch format for compatibility reasons). As such there is no need to change the internal delta algorithm in Git. You *can* change the difftool however in that way, so that `git diff` calls a custom difftool for specific file types.

Comment: poke, ok, then we need to override comparing algorithms both on client and server sides. I suppose that difftool is used only as a means of representing deltas to user, and is not used for generating patches.

Comment: @utapyngo Did you manage to get any acceptable solution after all? I am looking for the versioning of build results, something like executable files etc. But I figured out it is actually much more complicated problem, since .zip and all of sorts of archives will need to be properly versioned as well, thus require custom diffing anyway.

Comment: @AndreyTch.: no, I just used a custom diff and merge program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Server Side:
As far as I know (I´m no expert on this subject!) this is not easily done. So you´re best shot seems to get the source from Apache Subversion and modify/extend it according to your needs. Taking a look into "Pre-Commit Hooks" is also an idea.

For Client Side:
ClearCase has some nice extra Merge Tools for e.g. office documents.
Also it is possible to change the diff/merge tool in the Tortoise SVN Client.

Comment: Comparing of files is done at client side, only deltas are sent to the server. So it must be done at client side.

Comment: When you define custom diff/merge tool in svn client, will svn use it to find differences when commiting and updating? Or just to display the differences to the user? The 'svn commit' command does not seem to have the --diff-cmd argument.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of **git** , I don't know of any easy way to override the method for calculating the binary deltas that are used for efficient storage in pack files.  (Pack files are generated with most transports for efficient transport of data to and from the server.)

However, you might want to take a look at the [bup](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup) project for git.  This takes the approach of directly generating git pack files for the case of using git for backing-up huge amounts of data.  That sounds broadly similar to what you want to do.

[I understand that you explicitly exclude this in your question, but in case another reader finds this question who is interested in nice user-visible diffs of binary files, I'll point out [this useful example from Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html#diffing_binary_files).]

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely write plugins for Bazaar that provide custom merge algorithms:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/development/en/user-guide/hooks.html#example-a-merge-plugin
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/development/en/user-reference/hooks-help.html#merge-file-content

After a quick look I didn't see something like that for doing diffs, but I'm sure it will not be that hard to add something like that. I know there are plugins like bzr-tools that can provide alternative diff output (cdiff which prints the diff with some colour).